# Trigger Angular Ivy Change detection with Cypress

Tags: angular, ivy

I have the following Cypress test:

```
 ...

 describe('Form filling works properly, () => {
    it.only('should enable save button with correct form', () => {
      cy.get('input[name=notiName]').type('Test data for notiName, { force: true });
      cy.get('input[name=notiEnMessageName]').type('Test data for EnMessageName', { force: true 
    });

      cy.get('.navigationContainer [data-cy=btn-save]').should('be.enabled');
    });
  });
```

This works just fine.

But I have a third input value on the form, which is a complex data picker, and I would like to handle setting up value for it with its `formControl` instead of manually programming all the clicks required. Let's call the `formControl` `specialInputFormcontrol`˙for now.

So I do this:

```
 describe('New notification works properly', () => {
    it.only('should enable save button with correct form', () => {
      cy.get('input[name=notiName]').type('Test data for notiName, { force: true });
      cy.get('input[name=notiEnMessageName]').type('Test data for EnMessageName', { force: true 

      let angular;
      cy.window()
        .then((win) => angular = win.ng)
        .then(() => cy.document())
        .then((doc) => {
          cy.log('Angular component captured');
          const componentInstance = angular
            .getComponent(doc.querySelector('my-component-name'));

          componentInstance.specialInputFormcontrol.setValue("special value");

           // change detection here?
        });

      cy.get('.navigationContainer [data-cy=btn-save]').should('be.enabled');
    });
  });
```

My problem is, that although the value get updated, due to Angular's engine I still need to force a change detection tick, to apply the cahnges.

I have tried to place the following codes in place of the `// change detection here?` part as attempts at this:

```
  angular.applyChanges(componentInstance)
```

This resets the whole page.

```
  angular.applyChanges(angular.getComponent($0);
```

$0 is not defined.

```
   angular.probe(getAllAngularRootElements()[0]).injector.get(ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick()
```

angular.probe won't work in Ivy. (after angular 9)

```
   componentInstance.injector.get(angular.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick();
```

"TypeError: cannot read property 'get' of undefined".

**Update:**

```
          ɵdetectChanges(componentInstance);
```

As ChrisY pointed it out, after importing it I was able to call this, but got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

So as you can see, I looked up a few ideas, and none of the worked :(

Comment: Did not try it. How about: `import {ɵdetectChanges} from '@angular/core';` and 
`ɵdetectChanges(componentInstance);`

Comment: good idea, thank you! Unfortunately, it won't work either. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - one should use the angular debug hook to apply changes directly on the component reference like this:

```
describe('New notification works properly', () => {
    it.only('should enable save button with correct form', () => {
      cy.get('input[name=notiName]').type('Test data for notiName, { force: true });
      cy.get('input[name=notiEnMessageName]').type('Test data for EnMessageName', { force: true 

      let angular;
      cy.window()
        .then((win) => angular = win.ng)
        .then(() => cy.document())
        .then((doc) => {
          cy.log('Angular component captured');
          const componentInstance = angular
            .getComponent(doc.querySelector('my-component-name'));

          componentInstance.specialInputFormcontrol.setValue("special value");

          // Change detection trigger:
          angular.applyChanges(componentInstance)

        });

      cy.get('.navigationContainer [data-cy=btn-save]').should('be.enabled');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Work this solution also on productive angular project?

Comment: I became the follow error on execute per pipeline on server:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getComponent')

Comment: @SteffenKämmerer open a new question with describing your exact problem in greater detail. However, the error message means that the object you are calling the "getComponnet" function on, is undefined during runtime - maybe you did not select it properly?.

Comment: Im solved this problem with an unites in angular and delete the end to end test!